# Is it possible to directly access permanently deleted data from SSD without recovering it using recovery program?

Tags: memory-hardware

Is any technique present in this technical world regarding accessing data directly from any type of storing device without recovery it. For example if I deleted permanently data and then want to access it without recovering data using any software, but done some program as programmer and directly access that data without recovering it.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer hardware are off-topic here.

Comment: I think, this is a question for https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Define `deleted permanently` - shattering the glass platter of a yester-decade's hard disc moves recovery in the *government agency* realm, melting the last storage device the data is stored on to fiction. Similarly destroying the decryption key when the cypher "text" remains accessible renders the data unusable for what *should* be a lengthy period.

Comment: Because of `TRIM`, recovering data from an SSD probably requires someone to "hack" the SSD, essentially. On a hard drive, deleted data stays until it is overwritten, but SSDs have smart controllers that are overwriting data all the time.